# Summarizing a dataframe by date and group

Tags: r, pivot-table

I am trying to summarize a data set by a few different factors. Below is an example of my data:

```
household<-c("household1","household1","household1","household2","household2","household2","household3","household3","household3")
date<-c(sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 9))
value<-c(1:9)
type<-c("income","water","energy","income","water","energy","income","water","energy")
df<-data.frame(household,date,value,type)

   household       date value   type
1 household1 1999-05-10   100 income
2 household1 1999-05-25   200  water
3 household1 1999-10-12   300 energy
4 household2 1999-02-02   400 income
5 household2 1999-08-20   500  water
6 household2 1999-02-19   600 energy
7 household3 1999-07-01   700 income
8 household3 1999-10-13   800  water
9 household3 1999-01-01   900 energy
```

I want to summarize the data by month. Ideally the resulting data set would have 12 rows per household (one for each month) and a column for each category of expenditure (water, energy, income) that is a sum of that month's total.

I tried starting by adding a column with a short date, and then I was going to filter for each type and create a separate data frame for the summed data per transaction type. I was then going to merge those data frames together to have the summarized df. I attempted to summarize it using ddply, but it aggregated too much, and I can't keep the household level info.

```
ddply(df,.(shortdate),summarize,mean_value=mean(value))
  shortdate mean_value
1     14/07   15.88235
2     14/09    5.00000
3     14/10    5.00000
4     14/11   21.81818
5     14/12   20.00000
6     15/01   10.00000
7     15/02   12.50000
8     15/04    5.00000
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, I was just lazy and didn't type out the full df in the example

Comment: Yes, ideally I'd have 12 rows per hh (unless you can recommend a better way). This matches another df I have from another source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a pivot table. I like to use reshape::cast for these types of tables. If there is more than one value returned for a given expenditure type for a given household/year/month combination, this will sum those values. If there is only one value, it returns the value. The "sum" argument is not required but only placed there to handle exceptions. I think if your data is clean you shouldn't need this argument.

```
hh <- c("hh1", "hh1", "hh1", "hh2", "hh2", "hh2", "hh3", "hh3", "hh3")
date <- c(sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"),  9))
value <- c(1:9)
type <- c("income", "water", "energy", "income", "water", "energy", "income", "water", "energy")
df <- data.frame(hh,  date, value,  type)

# Load lubridate library, add date and year
library(lubridate)
df$month <- month(df$date)
df$year <- year(df$date)

# Load reshape library, run cast from reshape, creates pivot table
library(reshape)
dfNew <- cast(df, hh+year+month~type, value = "value", sum)

> dfNew
   hh year month energy income water
1 hh1 1999     4      3      0     0
2 hh1 1999    10      0      1     0
3 hh1 1999    11      0      0     2
4 hh2 1999     2      0      4     0
5 hh2 1999     3      6      0     0
6 hh2 1999     6      0      0     5
7 hh3 1999     1      9      0     0
8 hh3 1999     4      0      7     0
9 hh3 1999     8      0      0     8
```

Comment: If I am correct about the pivot table nature of your problem you may want to put that in the question somehow or tag it.

Comment: Yes, this actually a pivot table! Thanks for pointing this out. Worked perfectly and I made the edit in tags.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df$ym<-zoo::as.yearmon(as.Date(df$date), "%y/%m")
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ym,type) %>%
  summarise(mean_value=mean(value))

Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: ym [?]

             ym   type mean_value
  <S3: yearmon> <fctr>      <dbl>
1      jan 1999 income          1
2      jun 1999 energy          3
3      jul 1999 energy          6
4      jul 1999  water          2
5      ago 1999 income          4
6      set 1999 energy          9
7      set 1999 income          7
8      nov 1999  water          5
9      dez 1999  water          8
```

Edit: the wide format:

```
reshape2::dcast(dfr, ym ~ type)

        ym energy income water
1 jan 1999     NA      1    NA
2 jun 1999      3     NA    NA
3 jul 1999      6     NA     2
4 ago 1999     NA      4    NA
5 set 1999      9      7    NA
6 nov 1999     NA     NA     5
7 dez 1999     NA     NA     8
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly (from the description in the question), this is what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% mutate(date = lubridate::month(date)) %>%
    complete(household, date = 1:12) %>%
    spread(type, value) %>% group_by(household, date) %>% 
    mutate(Total = sum(energy, income, water, na.rm = T)) %>%
    select(household, Month = date, energy:water, Total)

#Source: local data frame [36 x 6]
#Groups: household, Month [36]
#
#    household Month energy income water Total
#       <fctr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  household1     1     NA     NA    NA     0
#2  household1     2     NA     NA    NA     0
#3  household1     3     NA     NA   200   200
#4  household1     4     NA     NA    NA     0
#5  household1     5     NA     NA    NA     0
#6  household1     6     NA     NA    NA     0
#7  household1     7     NA     NA    NA     0
#8  household1     8     NA     NA    NA     0
#9  household1     9    300     NA    NA   300
#10 household1    10     NA     NA    NA     0
# ... with 26 more rows
```

**Note**: I used the same `df` you provided in the question. The only change I made was the `value` column. Instead of `1:9`, I used `seq(100, 900, 100)`

If I got it wrong, please let me know and I will delete my answer. I will add an explanation of what's going on if this is correct.